# Recommended way to do a basic search

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, search

I need to do a search for the title of a video. The search will only be searching in one column of one table, so it is a very basic search. Here is what I am currently using to do the search:

```
video_set = video_set.filter(title__icontains=search)
```

and using `print connection.queries`, it turns into this --

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `userprofile_videoinfo` WHERE `userprofile_videoinfo`.`title` LIKE %search%
```

I am very new to search and SQL and it seems using '%like%' is the one thing that is always discouraged. I am searching through about 10,000 records and was wondering if this search would be adequate for such a small record size, or if I need to look to other options for search.  And if 10,000 records is too small to make a difference, at what size/when do I need to look towards other options? What options could I look to for a higher performance basic text search? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason people tell you to avoid doing like '%blah%' is because it's difficult to use an index when doing such a search. That means that if you don't have any other filters, it will have to do a full table scan and check each record to see if it matches your query instead of using an index. With 10,000 records, it's not going to be a significant performance hit. If you had 10x or 100x that many rows, then you'd start to notice slow downs. Full text search seems like overkill for 10,000 rows. There are other issues to consider though such as capitalization and sound-ex features that you may want to look into (as people often misspell words :) )

Comment: So for 10,000 movie titles, what would be the approximate performance/performance increase of using %like% vs. an indexed mysql search?

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you a specific % for all use cases. It'll depend on your hardware, configuration, whether or not the data is cached (or can be cached) in memory, etc. Don't optimize too early. If you have a rather well defined data set that you can load up and test your query against, that'll be the best way to know for your particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MyISAM tables, look into setting up [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) in your database and use the [MATCH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) function for your searches.

Answer (score 0):

If full-text-search capabilities of mysql are not enough for your needs. Have a look at Apache Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ or pylucene. They will give you much better results for the purpose of full-text search.